# Getting session Id in twig template

Tags: session

Is there a way to get the session id from craft.session in a twig template without needing to create a new filter?

Answer (score 3):

Old post, I know, but we've recently published a plugin to achieve this for a similar problem we were facing.

[SessionExposer plugin](https://github.com/madebymutual/SessionExposer) can help you achieve this. To get the Session ID in the template you use

```
{{ craft.sessionExposer.sessionId }}
```

Comment: Any idea if this plugin is still available somewhere? Need to do this on a legacy Craft2 site.

Comment: @erwinheiser yes I've restored it at https://github.com/madebymutual/SessionExposer now, please note it's archived and entirelty unsupported. But hopefully it works for you

Comment: That's awesome, many many thanks! I'll definitely check it out.

Comment: works as advertised, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to the PHP session ID (wrapped by [HttpSessionService](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/HttpSessionService))?

If so, the answer is no - Craft doesn't expose that to the templates.  You'd have to write a plugin that did.

Comment: Yes, I has hoping to grab the session to send along for a unique identifier for some tracking purposes. Looked at the request.getCookie() also but no luck.